# Get text from a <Div> tag from a html page to c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, html

How can I get the text in a div tag from a webpage to my .cs file (C#)?

I tested the html agility pack but it did not work I got different error and it's probably because this is a Windows Phone 7 project. Has anyone else any idea how to solve this?

Comment: ASP.NET application published on an IIS and viewed with a mobile or a fully fledged mobile app?

Comment: @BigMike Fully mobile application

Answer (score 0):

#### Silverlight C# Code

```
string text = HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("getDivText").ToString();
```

#### HTML

```
function getDivText() {
    return YourDivText;
}
```

Comment: I can´t access the html page, so that won´t work,  
unfortunately.

Comment: Then why are you trying to do this. Why don't you do a GET?

Answer (score 0):

HtmlAgilityPack should be what you need. Make sure you get it from the [NuGet](http://nuget.org), rather than directly from the project page, as the NuGet version includes a WP7 build.

**Update**

Windows Phone does not support synchronous networking APIs so HtmlAgilityPack can't support asynchronous loads. You need to pass a callback to LoadAsync to use it.

Comment: When I tried HtmlAgilityPack I did use this example:

HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://jsbin.com/owobe3");

HtmlNode rateNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='rate']");

string rate = rateNode.InnerText;

But Wp7 does now have the method "Load" as in web.Load so, I only have "LoadAsync" but when i try to use "LoadAsync" I get the message: Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument'

Do you have any idea whenthe problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create document from string not actual file you should use-

```
     doc.LoadHtml(string);
```

**EDIT**
This is how i use HtmlAgilityPack for parsing from webpage.(but this is in winForms)

```
      string page;
      using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
      {
          page = client.DownloadString(url);
      }

      HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();  
      doc.LoadHtml(page);


      string result;
      HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='obf']");
      result = node.InnerText;
```